# Global service hotkeys ignored in some applications

Tags: shortcut

I have defined some global hotkeys which run Automator services. These work fine everywhere except in two applications (iTerm2 and Emacs).

I would like to understand this better. Is it the case that these application grab the keyboard "harder" than others, and thus disable global shortcuts while they are in focus? Or do these shortcuts generally only function if an application doesn't handle the keypress (i.e., in any and all applications)?

EDIT: I do see these services in the system menu of the applications (even in those where the hotkeys don't work); and if I click them via that menu, they work fine.

Comment: Do you see them in emacs or iterm2 App menu > services?

Comment: @anki, I've updated the question (yes, I see them, and they work).